# Deployment Target Xcode - What should I support?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

I have a general question, which after researching I can't a clear answer.

Do apple recommend the default deployment target for my app. I want to use a  CocoaPods project, which uses minimum ios 10. This means my app won't run on devices before ios 10. Should I worry about this? Is from ios 10 and on OK?

Where can I get info about this?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Apple never mind about which iOS you support. Latest Xcode recommend iOS8 or higher.

Comment: This isn't really in the domain of SO questions. But it's worth noting that Apple has [a page noting what the iOS version adoption rates are](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/), which as of this writing shows 95% of devices on iOS 10 or above.

Comment: I would support the latest version - 1, which today would be iOS 10